# Device Font Size

Tags: android, fonts, font-size

Is there any way of knowing what font size is being set on the phone, i.e under the

```
settings > display > font = small/normal/large/huge
```

Inside my app ? I need to change the height of a view based on the device font size. Is there any way of doing this ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the device's font scale using:

```
float scale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
```

Comment: Thank you! Also,say the font size of a textview is set to 15sp in my app, how is the conversion done when I change the device font size ? With respect to fontscale is it 15*1.15 for large, or is it something else ?